# Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, json, api, google-chrome-extension

I have a few questions that need answering. I am trying to create a Google Chrome extension and I need every page to be monitored for a keyboard action. I have added a content script that runs on the page load and when you click the keyboard shortcut an alert is shown.

What I want to do is instead of an alert have something like fancybox, thickbox, etc... however all of those are jquery plugins which adds a dependency to my js file. I tried launching the plugin before my js file but it still does not work.

I run the content script from the manifest.json file with

`"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches":["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
        "run_at":"document_start",
        "js":["jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1.min.js", "shortcuts.js"]
    }
   ],`

I cannot execute an HTML page where the js is located I have to use a js file.

so what I want to know is if either there is a way to include the plugin without physically adding it to my file or if there is a way to call the js file which then just executes an HTML file or if there is another way of creating a popup screen like fancybox that is already included in js.

Another question I have is if there was a way to embed HTML into an alert box (this is a backup if I cannot figure out the above question)

and finally does anyone know of an execution command for x-webkit-speech? I want the command to start recording and somehow some people have used some commands (none of which answer my question) so someone somewhere knows a little more about this function then me. I would really appreciate help with this I am really close to finishing my program and these are my last holdups with these questions answered I will be able to release my extension. Please help where you can I have researched and researched everywhere all different ways of trying these things and none have worked.

---

edit:

You were correct (JHurrah) including the jquery actually solved the problem I really appreciate that. simple yet successful I just assumed the jquery provided was enough but I guess everyone knows what happens when you assume especially when programming.

NewTang I have already looked at that website however I will relook at it and see if I missed anything thanks for the help

---

yeah see I don't have that I have link edit and flag I looked all over and did not see an add comment button at all... :[

Comment: note that you can also comment directly on answers with the `add comment` link underneath each one. :) That way, other users can more easily follow the flow of conversation, and questions can stay lean and mean.

Answer (score 1):

since simplemodal is a plugin it depends on jquery, try including jquery in your manifest before the other scripts.

```
"js":["jquery-1.5.2.min.js", "jquery.simplemodal.1.4.1.min.js", "shortcuts.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I"m a little confused by your question, but I'll give it my best shot.

1) I think you're trying to ask: Can I use a content_script to inject HTML.  The answer is yes, but only through Javascript.  So, you could have something like:

```
//using jquery
$("body").append("Hi, I'm on the bottom of the page");
```

Your javascript would have to create or load the HTML that would get inserted into the page.

2) No, no HTML in an alert box.  You're on the right track with using lightbox, thickbox, etc.

3) There's not many resources on x-webkit-speech, but maybe this can help you get going: http://nooshu.com/experimenting-with-webkit-form-speech-input